# Why does table style move out when rendering rows through vue component

Tags: html, css, vue.js

When I hardcode rows in my html-table, all styles are OK, but when I render them via Vue component using v-for directive, my columns in the table move out:
Here are hardcored rows:

```
 <table class="table_body">

                       <tr class="main_table_tr" >
                        <td class="main_table_td column_1">999999</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_2">0000000001</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_3">001001</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_4">Name</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_5">serial-01-02-03</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_6">2020-12-20</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_7">98547</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_8">шт.</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_9">77777.77</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_10">88888.77</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_11">999999999</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_12">999999999</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_13">2020-12-20 12:20:00</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_14"> Supplier Name </td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_15">Type</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_16">Surname Name</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="main_table_tr" >
                        <td class="main_table_td column_1">999999</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_2">0000000001</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_3">001001</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_4">Name</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_5">serial-01-02-03</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_6">2020-12-20</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_7">98547</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_8">шт.</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_9">77777.77</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_10">88888.77</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_11">999999999</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_12">999999999</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_13">2020-12-20 12:20:00</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_14"> Supplier Name </td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_15">Type</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_16">Surname Name</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="main_table_tr" >
                        <td class="main_table_td column_1">999999</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_2">0000000001</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_3">001001</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_4">Name</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_5">serial-01-02-03</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_6">2020-12-20</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_7">98547</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_8">шт.</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_9">77777.77</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_10">88888.77</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_11">999999999</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_12">999999999</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_13">2020-12-20 12:20:00</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_14"> Supplier Name </td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_15">Type</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_16">Surname Name</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

Here are rendered rows:

```
 <table class="table_body">
  <tr class="main_table_tr" is="app-skuins" :list-of-rows="listOfRows"></tr>
 </table>
```

And a template which I render to:

```
template: `<div>
       <tr class="main_table_tr" >
                        <td class="main_table_td column_1">999999</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_2">0000000001</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_3">001001</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_4">Name</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_5">serial-01-02-03</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_6">2020-12-20</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_7">98547</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_8">шт.</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_9">77777.77</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_10">88888.77</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_11">999999999</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_12">999999999</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_13">2020-12-20 12:20:00</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_14"> Supplier Name </td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_15">Type</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_16">Surname Name</td>
                    </tr> 
 <tr class="main_table_tr" >
                        <td class="main_table_td column_1">999999</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_2">0000000001</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_3">001001</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_4">Name</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_5">serial-01-02-03</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_6">2020-12-20</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_7">98547</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_8">шт.</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_9">77777.77</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_10">88888.77</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_11">999999999</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_12">999999999</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_13">2020-12-20 12:20:00</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_14"> Supplier Name </td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_15">Type</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_16">Surname Name</td>
                    </tr> 
 <tr class="main_table_tr" >
                        <td class="main_table_td column_1">999999</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_2">0000000001</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_3">001001</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_4">Name</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_5">serial-01-02-03</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_6">2020-12-20</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_7">98547</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_8">шт.</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_9">77777.77</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_10">88888.77</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_11">999999999</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_12">999999999</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_13">2020-12-20 12:20:00</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_14"> Supplier Name </td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_15">Type</td>
                        <td class="main_table_td column_16">Surname Name</td>
                    </tr>       
        </div>`,
```

[image: This style is OK]

[image: This style moved]

**SOLVED:**
So, the tbody option really helped:

This is what in HTML page:

```
<table class="table_body">
   <tbody is="app-skuins" :list-of-rows="listOfRows"></tbody>
</table>
```

This is what I render through Vue component:

```
template: `<tbody>
        <tr class="main_table_tr" v-for="(row, index) in listOfRows">
        <td class="main_table_td column_1">{{index + 1}}</td>
        <td class="main_table_td column_2">{{row.inDoc.docNumber}}</td>
        <td class="main_table_td column_3">{{row.sku.code}}</td>
        <td class="main_table_td column_4">{{row.sku.name}} </td>
        <td class="main_table_td column_5">{{row.serial}} </td>
        <td class="main_table_td column_6">{{row.expireDate}} </td>
        <td class="main_table_td column_7">{{row.qty}}</td>   
        <td class="main_table_td column_8">{{row.sku.unit.unit}}</td>  
        <td class="main_table_td column_9">{{row.price}}</td>  
        <td class="main_table_td column_10">{{row.vatPrice}}</td>  
        <td class="main_table_td column_11">{{row.total}}</td>  
        <td class="main_table_td column_12">{{row.vatTotal}}</td>  
        <td class="main_table_td column_13">{{row.inDoc.docDate}}</td>  
        <td class="main_table_td column_14">{{row.inDoc.contractor.name}}</td>  
        <td class="main_table_td column_15">{{row.inDoc.type.docType}}</td>  
        <td class="main_table_td column_16">{{row.inDoc.owner.fullName}}</td>         
        </tr>        
        </tbody>`,
```

Thanks a lot everyone!

Comment: I'm not familiar with Vue templates but there is one thing that stands out along with one question. First, unless vue requires it, why wrap your `TR` with a `div`? The question is do you have the correct number of columns compared to your input row above?

Comment: Try changing the `<div>` to a `<tbody>`.

Comment: Vue requires one root element when rendering component template, that's why I you can’t do without <div>. I also thought that the problem was in this <div>, so I hardcoded div element too when I hardcoded my rows. And its presence does not affect the style when I hardcod rows. Yes, number of columns corresponds of course

Comment: skirtle: Tried <tbody> right now - did not help.

Comment: You're going to need to inspect the generated DOM and compare the two cases to establish what the difference is. The only other thing that catches my eye is the class `main_table_tr`, which you should probably remove from the outer template because it'll be applied to the wrong element of the child.

Comment: Thank U,  the tbody option really helped. See update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably happens because it renders invalid HTML. Your template contains a `<div>` as parent of `<tr>` which is invalid. Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr (under "Permitted parents")

Comment: Vue requires one root element when rendering component template, that's why I you can’t do without <div>.
I also thought that the problem was in this <div>, so I hardcoded div element too when I hardcoded my rows. And its presence does not affect the style when I hardcod rows

Comment: You could change `<div>` to `<tbody>` to actually have at least have valid HTML. What is `:list-of-rows` actually doing?

Comment: Tried <tbody> right now - did not help.  :list-of-rows - is a custom directive in Vue to pass data array to the component

Comment: Okay. Seems a bit weird to me that you pass data array to the component (tr), which in turn generates a new template with tr again. Have you checked how the rendered HTML is actually structured in a browser?

Comment: Yes, I have checked. The fact is that the other tables style is OK when I render them just the same way. But exactly this table for some reason behaves differently in rendering while it is OK in simple hardcoded html. I suspect this is some kind of strangeness of Vue.js

Comment: In this case, I got out of the situation by making <table> element as a root, but this is a special case, because I use one <table></table> as a header and other <table></table>  as a body. But if use  <table><thead></thead><tbody></tbody><tr class="main_table_tr" is="app-skuins" :list-of-rows="listOfRows"></tr></table> structure, then the problem remains open (((

Comment: Can you expand your question with the actually rendered HTML of the solution which isn't working?

Comment: The tbody option really helped. See update. Thank U very much!

Comment: No problem. You probably should mark an answer as correct then.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding an extra div on your template, remove it:

```
template: `
    <tr class="main_table_tr" v-for="(row, index) in listOfRows">
    <td class="main_table_td column_1">{{index + 1}}</td>
    <td class="main_table_td column_2">{{row.inDoc.docNumber}}</td>
    <td class="main_table_td column_3">{{row.sku.code}}</td>
    <td class="main_table_td column_4">{{row.sku.name}} </td>
    <td class="main_table_td column_5">{{row.serial}} </td>
    <td class="main_table_td column_6">{{row.expireDate}} </td>
    <td class="main_table_td column_7">{{row.qty}}</td>   
    <td class="main_table_td column_8">{{row.sku.unit.unit}}</td>  
    <td class="main_table_td column_9">{{row.price}}</td>  
    <td class="main_table_td column_10">{{row.vatPrice}}</td>  
    <td class="main_table_td column_11">{{row.total}}</td>  
    <td class="main_table_td column_12">{{row.vatTotal}}</td>  
    <td class="main_table_td column_13">{{row.inDoc.docDate}}</td>  
    <td class="main_table_td column_14">{{row.inDoc.contractor.name}}</td>  
    <td class="main_table_td column_15">{{row.inDoc.type.docType}}</td>  
    <td class="main_table_td column_16">{{row.inDoc.owner.fullName}}</td>         
    </tr>`,
```

Comment: I can't remove it, it is a Vue.js requirement, otherwise I get error "Component template should contain exactly one root element."
As I wrote above, this div does not affect the style in any way if I hardcode it too